# How do I print an object's property to the Debugger Console in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging

I have an object that was created with the Core Data code generator:

.h file:

```
@interface MyObject :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation MyObject
@dynamic title;
@end
```

I put a breakpoint and now I want to print the `title` property of one of its instances (`myObject`) to the console.

---

When I try `po myObject.title`, I get the error:

> There is no member named title.

When I try `po [myObject title]`, I get the error:

> Target does not respond to this message selector.

When I try `myObject.title` in the Expressions window, I get the error:

> out of scope

... even though `myObject` in the same window allows me to see some of its members.

---

How can I print an object's property to the console and/or Expressions window in Xcode?

Answer (score 16):

You can get around this by using valueForKey -

```
po [myObject valueForKey:@"title"]
```

which gets tiresome pretty quickly, but works ok.